# OpenCV: Recognizing discontinuous digits - multiple contour boxes problem

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, digits

I am following this [tutorial](https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) to recognize six digits from the following image
[image]

The threshold seems (to me) to be very good
[image]
However, when I reach the contour definition, digits 7, 1, 0 (and possibly more) are always split in two or more boxes.
[image]
By definition, a contour is a boundary of a *continuous* entity, which means that these digits separated by a small ligature cannot be classified as such. What to do in this case? My first instinct is to try and merge these small boxes? I have already tried to play around with the height and width of the contour with no success. The code is written below.

```py
# https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2
# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
    (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
    (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 1,
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0): 2,
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
    (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
    (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
    (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
    (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9
}

# load the example image
image = cv2.imread('DSC_01922.JPG', 1)
# pre-process the image by resizing it, converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
# image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

# threshold the warped image, then apply a series of morphological
# operations to cleanup the thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
# digit contours lists
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
digitCnts = []
# loop over the digit area candidates
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
    if (h >= 90 and h <= 300):
            digitCnts.append(c)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Update 1**

Using MORPH_CLOSE instead of OPEN and enlarging the kernel as suggested by @Croolman improves the results as can be seen below

```py
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 7))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image]

Note that I am doing this as a hobby and I am not familiar with/doing research on existent tools of OpenCV/python. Thank you in advance.

**Update 2**

This solution works.

```py
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 15))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

threshold
[image]
contour
[image]

Comment: The issue is, you re using different image than the guy in the tutorial. He never states that his solution is universal to any image input. It works for him, not for you. You will have to do some changes to reach the same result. Merging the bounding boxes would be one, but a very tricky one. The easiest one would be to enlarge the kernel for morphology in your case. Try 1,7 or even widen up 3,7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete answer. It required tweeking the kernel values + using morph_close

```py
# https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2
# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
    (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
    (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 1,
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0): 2,
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
    (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
    (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
    (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
    (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9
}

# load the example image
image = cv2.imread('DSC_01922.JPG', 1)
# pre-process the image by resizing it, converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
# image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

# threshold the warped image, then apply a series of morphological
# operations to cleanup the thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 15))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
# digit contours lists
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
digitCnts = []
# loop over the digit area candidates
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
    if (h >= 90 and h <= 300):
            digitCnts.append(c)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```